# How to fix InvalidSignatureException in my Amazon SES SendRawEmail PHP code

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I read the Amazon SES documentation several times and came up with the below PHP code to send an email via Amazon SES using what they called as HTTPS Query API approach to send emails without using the Amazon AWS SDK for PHP. However I am stuck with InvalidSignatureException and am unable to get past it. It seems like I am making a mistake somewhere probably in (1) creating the request signature or in (2) selecting right data to generate the request signature from. Any help to fix my code is greatly appreciated. My code is available below. It is important that I do this approach without including the Amazon AWS SDK into my PHP code. Thank you.

```
define("EMAIL_TO", <Amazon SES configured & verified from email id>);
define("EMAIL_FROM", <Amazon SES configured & verified from email id>);
define("SMTP_USERNAME", <AWS ACCESS KEY>);
define("SMTP_PASSWORD", <AWS SECRET ACCESS KEY>);

function amazonsesrawmailcurlpost($strToEmailId, $strEmailSubject, $strEmailBody)
{
    $strDateRFC2822 = date("r", time());

    $strRawEmailData = "From: ".EMAIL_FROM."\n";
    $strRawEmailData.= "Subject: $strEmailSubject\n";
    $strRawEmailData.= "\n";
    $strRawEmailData.= $strEmailBody;

    $strRequestContentPart = "Action=SendRawEmail";
    $strRequestContentPart.= "&Destinations.member.1=$strToEmailId";
    $strRequestContentPart.= "&RawMessage.Data=".base64_encode($strRawEmailData);
    $strRequestContentPart = urlencode($strRequestContentPart);

    $nRequestContentPartLength = strlen($strRequestContentPart);

    $strSignature = base64_encode(hash_hmac(
        "sha256",
        $strDateRFC2822,
        SMTP_PASSWORD,
        TRUE
    ));

    $rCurlToMailer = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($rCurlToMailer, CURLOPT_URL, "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/");
    curl_setopt($rCurlToMailer, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($rCurlToMailer,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array(
            "POST / HTTP/1.1",
            "Host: email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
            "Date: $strDateRFC2822",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length: $nRequestContentPartLength",
            "X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=".SMTP_USERNAME.", Algorithm=HmacSHA256, Signature=$strSignature"
        )
    );

    curl_setopt($rCurlToMailer, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($rCurlToMailer, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strRequestContentPart);

    $strMailerResponse = curl_exec($rCurlToMailer);
    echo $strMailerResponse;
    curl_close($rCurlToMailer);
}
amazonsesrawmailcurlpost(EMAIL_TO, "amazonses test mail", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Comment: Can I ask why you can't or are unwilling to use their SDK?

Comment: Can you please provide the full error? There should be a stack trace etc.

Comment: @ Ohgodwhy: The code runs fine, there is no stack trace. The server is throwing back InvalidSignatureException. 

<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>

Comment: @ cmorrissey: Amazon SES provided a couple of approaches and I picked this one. I don't feel like giving up on this approach without trying enough. Also their SDK requires me to upgrade my PHP version. Even though I do it on my PC, its a long process to upgrade my production PHP version. That's why I am unwilling to use their SDK

Answer (score 0):

Signature Version 3 with HTTPS, used by SES, is starkly different than V2 or V4 commonly seen with other AWS services, in that the *only* thing you sign is the *date value*.

> To create the string to sign, calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC hash with the Date header value, your secret access key as the key, and SHA256 or SHA1 as the hash algorithm.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-authentication.html

Note also that all the keys and values in a `POST` with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` need to actually be... urlencoded.  I don't see this in your code.  It isn't going to be related to the error but may cause additional issues later.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Michael. I really appreciate you looking into my problem. Updating my code accordingly by (i) taking only the date value in RFC2822 format to sign (ii) using PHP's hash_hmac method to generate its hash in SHA256 algorithm using my secret key and (iii) adding the result has base64 as signature in authorization header, unfortunately has still resulted in the same InvalidSignatureException.

Comment: Note: I updated my code above to reflect the changes you suggested.